# 500 Internal Server Error in MERN Stack WHILE DEFINING NEW USER IN MERN

Tags: javascript, express, mern, internal-server-error

```
router.post("/register", async(req, res) => {
try {
      const { uname, email, phoneNumber, password } = req.body;
 
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
      if (existingUser)
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "an account with this email already exist" });
      const existingPhone = await User.findOne({ phoneNumber: phoneNumber });
      if (existingPhone)
          return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Phone number already registered" });

      const newUser = new User({
         uname,
         email,
         phoneNumber,
         password
     });
     const savedUser = await newUser.save();
     res.json(savedUser);
     console.log("data enter");
     return res.json({ msg: "sucedddddd" });
 } catch (err) {
 res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

> 

The above is my code, and Server is working. I wrote other route and its working. now error is
occuring at where I newUser is declared and further. Earlier it was working,now Its giving me 500
Internal Server Error

Comment: i dont think you can do res.json(savedUser) and then res.json({msg:"suceddddd"}) again. The response must have ended and then the stream be written after